# Replace a string in shell script using a variable

Tags: unix, shell, sed

I am using the below code for replacing a string
inside a shell script.

```
echo $LINE | sed -e 's/12345678/"$replace"/g'
```

but it's getting replaced with `$replace` instead of the value of that variable.

Could anybody tell what went wrong?

Comment: For the common related question about handling values with slashes in them, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70476292/925775

Answer (score 199, accepted):

If you want to interpret `$replace`, you should not use single quotes since they prevent variable substitution.

Try:

```
echo $LINE | sed -e "s/12345678/${replace}/g"
```

Transcript:

```
pax> export replace=987654321
pax> echo X123456789X | sed "s/123456789/${replace}/"
X987654321X
pax> _
```

Just be careful to ensure that `${replace}` doesn't have any characters of significance to `sed` (like `/` for instance) since it will cause confusion unless escaped. But if, as you say, you're replacing one number with another, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: i dont want the quotes put in.i want one number to be replaced with other

Comment: paxdiablo: `set` is also not necessary (and how were you going to use it anyway?). Just `replace=987654321`.

Comment: I usually always use `export` to ensure that variables are set for children but, as you say, you could just as easily avoid it. However, the use or not of `export` is irrelevant here (a style issue) and has no effect on the actual answer, which is how to use variables within a `sed` command.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to be working with the `-i` option. Would you know why? or how to make it work?

Comment: @Gabriel, if you mean `sed -i`, that requirs an input file so it can do in-place editing. I'm hoping you're not trying to use `echo something | sed -i 'command'` since that has no input file to modify, just the input stream. You would have to use `sed -i 'command' some_file_name`. Suggest you open up another question with more detail if it's something other than that.

Comment: Maybe also point out that switching from single to double quotes requires any `$` or `\`` in the `sed` script to be escaped with a backslash, to protect it from the shell's substitution mechanism for double-quoted strings.

Comment: if line is delimited like this: `abc,123,def,456,ghi`, and i want to replace 4th element with a value from variable `$var`, how could it be done?

Answer (score 100):

you can use the shell (bash/ksh).

```
$ var="12345678abc"
$ replace="test"
$ echo ${var//12345678/$replace}
testabc
```

Comment: May want to mention that's bash-specific (and ksh?). Probably not of import to most people but some of us are still forced to work on ancient UNIXen :-)

Comment: Beware, this also fails on dash, which is `/bin/sh` on many modern Linuxes.

Comment: why need two forward slashes after the "var"? one should be enough according to my test.

Comment: You need to slashes if you want global replace, rather than the first instance.

Answer (score 43):

Not specific to the question, but for folks who need the same kind of functionality expanded for clarity from previous answers:

```
# create some variables
str="someFileName.foo"
find=".foo"
replace=".bar"
# notice the the str isn't prefixed with $
#    this is just how this feature works :/
result=${str//$find/$replace}
echo $result    
# result is: someFileName.bar

str="someFileName.sally"
find=".foo"
replace=".bar"
result=${str//$find/$replace}
echo $result    
# result is: someFileName.sally because ".foo" was not found
```

Comment: You can find the docs in https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/bash1.html. Look for `${parameter/pattern/string}`

Answer (score 24):

Found a [graceful solution](https://www.shellscript.sh/tips/pattern-substitution/).

```
echo ${LINE//12345678/$replace}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the useful tutorial : )

Answer (score 12):

Single quotes are very strong. Once inside, there's nothing you can do to invoke variable substitution, until you leave. Use double quotes instead:

```
echo $LINE | sed -e "s/12345678/$replace/g"
```

Answer (score 9):

Let me give you two examples.

- Using sed:

```
#!/bin/bash
LINE="12345678HI"
replace="Hello"
echo $LINE | sed -e "s/12345678/$replace/g"
```

- Without Using sed:

```
LINE="12345678HI"
str_to_replace="12345678"
replace_str="Hello"
result=${str//$str_to_replace/$replace_str}
echo $result
```

Hope you will find it helpful!

Comment: finaly one tt works

Answer (score 5):

```
echo $LINE | sed -e 's/12345678/'$replace'/g'
```

you can still use single quotes, but you have to "open" them when you want the variable expanded at the right place. otherwise the string is taken "literally" (as @paxdiablo correctly stated, his answer is correct as well)

Comment: This has the problem that using `$replace` outside of any quotes will cause the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on the value. This will appear to work with simple values, but could blow up dramatically on nontrivial strings. Don't use this in production code.

Answer (score 3):

To let your shell expand the variable, you need to use double-quotes like

```
sed -i "s#12345678#$replace#g" file.txt
```

This will break if `$replace` contain special `sed` characters (`#`, `\`). But you can preprocess `$replace` to quote them:

```
replace_quoted=$(printf '%s' "$replace" | sed 's/[#\]/\\\0/g')
sed -i "s#12345678#$replace_quoted#g" file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

use @ if you want to replace things like /. $ etc.

```
result=$(echo $str | sed "s@$oldstr@$newstr@g")
```

the above code will replace all occurrences of the specified replacement term
if you want, remove the ending `g` which means that the only first occurrence will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement to this but my replace var contained an ampersand. Escaping the ampersand like this solved my problem:

```
replace="salt & pepper"
echo "pass the salt" | sed "s/salt/${replace/&/\&}/g"
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead

```
echo $LINE | sed -e 's/12345678/$replace/g'
```

this works for me just simply remove the quotes

Answer (score -2):

I prefer to use double quotes , as single quptes are very powerful as we used them if dont able to change anything inside it or can invoke the variable substituion .

so use double quotes instaed.

```
echo $LINE | sed -e "s/12345678/$replace/g"
```

Comment: Is this any different from Dave's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6756853/2235132)?