# How to use variables in sed

Tags: sed

How to use variables in sed command?

ex: `sed '/Jagan/s/Hi/HELLO/' file`

here i want to replace `Hi` with a variable

```
var1=Hi
sed '/Jagan/s/$var1/HELLO/' file
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace a string in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306007/replace-a-string-in-shell-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"` instead of `'`:

```
sed "/Jagan/s/$var1/HELLO/"
```

**Edit:** The double quote `"` allows the shell to expand variables inside a string. The single quote `'` doesn't allow this.

Comment: What is the difference in using single `'` and `"` ?