# passing variables to sed command

Tags: bash, sed

i am trying to run the following in a script. It basically appends TXT_NEW after TXT with the define variables. Running the script wrapped in a small bash script throws an error:

sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

```
#!/bin/bash

user="Alpine"
new_user="Volverine"
file_name=file.txt

TXT="This Text is by $user"
TXT_NEW="This is owned by $new_dev"

sed -i "'/$TXT/a ${TXT_NEW}'" $file
```

In order to trouble shoot i echoed the sed command using as follows:

```
echo sed -i "'/$TXT/a ${TXT_NEW}'" $file
```

And i see the variables expand correctly like this:

```
sed -i '/This Text is by Alpine/a This is owned by Volverine' file.txt
```

Appreciate if someone can have a look and provide some pointers...

Comment: try removing the single quotes within double quotes... and typo, it should be `"$file_name"` not `$file`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use variables in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851521/how-to-use-variables-in-sed)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have a problem with double quoting. Single quotes inside outer double quotes are making `sed` fail, since it's reading the first character `'` as an invalid command.

So, just remove those and the example you provided should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
user="Alpine"
new_user="Volverine"
file_name="file.txt"

TXT="This Text is by $user"
TXT_NEW="This is owned by $new_user"

sed -i "/$TXT/a ${TXT_NEW}" "$file_name"
```

---

However, since your question is about **passing a variable text** to `sed` append command, you might consider using the *append from file command*, `r <filename>`, like this:

```
sed -i "/$TXT/r /dev/stdin" $file_name <<<"$TXT_NEW"
```

The `r` command is similar to `a` (append text), but it reads the text to be appended from the file specified. If we say to read from `/dev/stdin` (should work in `bash`), we can provide the text via [here-string](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html).

Another thing you should do **to generalize** this is to handle `sed` regex metacharacters in your "search string" variable `$TXT`, by escaping `\`, `/` and `&`. Perhaps via a helper function `escape()`:

```
escape() {
    sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g' <<<"$1";
}
sed -i "/$(escape "$TXT")/r /dev/stdin" $file_name <<<"$TXT_NEW"
```