# Replace a slash with the word 'slash' in Korn shell scripting

Tags: c, shell, unix, ksh

I am using a `while` loop to read a file line by line and, for example, if the file contains a line like:

```
ABC.///.AB_SWift_ABC
```

I need to replace it with

```
ABC.slashslashslash.AB_SWift_ABC
```

How can I do that with a Korn shell?

Comment: Here you go https://www.google.com/search?q=c+replace+substring

Comment: shell in c...`echo "ABC.///.AB_SWift_ABC" | sed 's/\//slash/g'` :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace a string in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306007/replace-a-string-in-shell-script)

Comment: What you show are forward slashes (`/`), not backslashes (``\``).

Comment: Also why first word you want in lower case?

Comment: @pravin_23 ok..find answer.

Comment: @BMW : NO i need to use backslashes only .

Comment: @pravin_23: you don't seem to understand the difference between slashes and backslashes.  There isn't a backslash visible in your question except spelled out as the word 'backslash'.

Comment: Sorry @jonathan My wrong ..thanks for pointing out :) Mistakes help us to learn

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bash`, you can use the variable substring replacement functionality.

```
>> a=ABC.///.AB_SWift_ABC
>> echo $a
ABC.///.AB_SWift_ABC
>> echo ${a//\//slash}
ABC.slashslashslash.AB_SWift_ABC
```

Comment: i am using KSh @ R Sahu

Answer (score 0):

Why are you reading line by line?  It would be quicker to simply run `sed` on the file:

```
sed 's%/%slash%g'
```

If you must do it in Bash, then use the substitute [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
${line//\//slash}
```

You mention backslashes but use forward slashes, which is confusing.  If, perchance, you mean backslashes, then:

```
sed 's/\\/slash/g'
${lines//\\/slash}
```

Comment: i am reading a file line by line and doing some process in it. after the processing i am trying to create a new file .

example : if the line  is like ABC.ABC_swift_Q i am amble to create a file . 

if the line consists of names like this ABC.///.AB_SWift_ABC there exists a problem ...

some process > home/dir/ABC.ABC_swift_Q  --here file gets created 
if some process > home/dir/ABC.///.AB_SWift_ABC  --here it takes ABC  as a directory so i am trying to replace / with SLASH

Comment: OK; then if you've read the line (file name) into `$line` (with `read line` or minor variants on the theme), you can write `mapped=${line//\//slash}` and then use `"$mapped"` where you need the name without slashes and `"$line"` where you need the name with slashes.

Comment: When i try doing it in Kshell ,it gives me bad substituion error

Comment: Yes; Korn shell is not Bash.  AFAIK, you'll need to use a `sed`-based solution in Korn shell: `mapped=$(echo "$line" | sed 's%/%slash%g')`.

Answer (score 0):

In `c` you can replace `/` by `slash` using bash command like

```
char cmd[]="sed -i 's|/|slash|g' file";
system(cmd);
```

So not require read file line by line.