# why sed not working properly in script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hi I have following line in shellscript

```
sed 's_$org_$repl_g' $i > $temp_file
```

In this $org denotes the name to be change and $repl denotes replacement. I have done echo for both and both are write. $i represent the file name. when I echo below

```
echo $(sed "s/$org/$repl_g" $i)
```

Then also it does not replace the word . while when I try this with terminal directly as below

```
sed 's_Dilip_Agarwal_g' test.txt
```

then it give correct output by replacing the original one.

Can any body help me where I am wrong in this.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming that the parentheses are matched, use " instead of ' in your script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace a string in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306007/replace-a-string-in-shell-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use command substitution on it. And use double quotes instead of single quotes. Single quotes do not expand parameters. You also have to fix your parameter expansion. `_` is also a valid parameter character so you need to use braces to isolate the only characters that would identify the parameters.

```
sed "s_${org}_${repl}_g" "$i" > "$temp_file"
```

You can also just use another delimeter that's not a parameter character:

```
sed "s|$org|$repl|g" "$i" > "$temp_file"
```