# Delete lines from input file after exact matching the prefix path till $(pwd) in the file

Tags: bash, shell

```
File.txt
/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd
/aaa/bbb/ccc/mmm
/aaa/eee/ccc/ddd
```

if my `$(pwd)` is `/aaa/bbb/ccc`
the it should delete only first two
I have tried like `sed /^$(pwd)/d` but not worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using `$(pwd)`, which tries to execute a command `pwd`. This result contains slashes, so that the final command is something like:

```
sed /^/aaa/bbb/ccc/d
```

Which `sed` cannot handle and returns an error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 4: extra characters after command

You should instead use another delimiter. For example, `_`:

```
sed "\_${PWD}_d"
```

As [123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4923629/123) comments below, you need to escape the first delimiter if it is not a substitution. I also enclose the var within `${ }` to prevent the variable to be considered `PWD_` instead of `PWD`.

You can use `awk` for a nicer approach:

```
$ awk -v patt="$PWD" '!($0 ~ patt)' file
/aaa/eee/ccc/ddd
```

Note `$PWD` is the same as executing `pwd`.

Comment: You can also use different delimiters for sed.

Comment: @123 I tried and I do use them for the `sed 's/XXX/YYY/g` syntax, but I couldn't for the `sed /ZZZ/d`.

Comment: You need to escape the first delimiter if it is not a substitution. i.e `sed "\:$string:d"`

Comment: @123 oh, great discovery! I wasn't aware of that (do you have any source?). Many thanks, updated

Comment: It's in the man page in the addresses section. `\cregexpc >>
              Match lines matching the regular expression regexp.  The c may be any character`

Comment: @fedorqui My directory has the _ in name so I used @ instead. `sed "\@${PWD}@d" file.txt`. It worked great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` can also do the job:

```
grep -v "$(pwd)" file
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to precise the answer of fedorqui...

In your question there is another problem because you variable $pwd contain special sed symbols (/).
So the sed will not be glad...

Some solution for example could be find here : [Replace a string in shell script using a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306007/replace-a-string-in-shell-script-using-a-variable)

So you could use additional variable to correct this problem.

This work perfectly for your example (I just replace echo $(pwd) by 'echo /aaa/bbb/ccc').

```
pwd_bis=$( echo $(pwd) | sed 's/[\/]/\\\0/g' )
sed "/^${pwd_bis}/d" File.txt
```