# How would the output of my variable have spaces?

Tags: unix

I am looking to declare variables to have an output of—for my email subject:

value_value_value_value_value

I would need my variable outputs to have spaces in between, I am trying to add email subject using the variable. Please see my code:

```
var1=$1
var2=$2
var3=$3
var4=$4$5$6


echo "email content

$var2 $var3

email content $ticketnumber

email content,
" | mail -s  $var4  testmail@gmail.com -- -f testmail@gmail.com
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash script variable declaration - command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/bash-script-variable-declaration-command-not-found)

Comment: I don't really understand what your trying to do. you can also try sed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306007/replace-a-string-in-shell-script-using-a-variable

Comment: I am trying to automate my email sending—I need my subject to be a variable as its not a constant—when I am outputting my subject it doesn't have spaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to concatenate your variables:

```sh
var4="$var4"_"$var5"_"$var6"
```

The `_` inbetween the variables is as per your original question, not as reflected in your sample code.

If you need spaces, you can change it to:

```sh
var4="$var4"" ""$var5"" ""$var6"
```

Comment: And you my friend roelofs are the MAN! El Hombre!