# How to insert variable containing a path into sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I'm writing a linux script, which is to replace a string for a file. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
var=./video/example.mp4
`sed -i '' 's/sceneFilePath:.*/sceneFilePath: "$var",/g' test`
```

In the file named `test`, there is a line like this:

```
sceneFilePath: "t.mp4",
```

What I need is to replace this line with the line below:

```
sceneFilePath: "./video/example.mp4",
```

It means that things between double quotes should be replaced by the `$var`.

However when I execute my script, I get `sceneFilePath: "$var",`.

I've read this answer: [Replace a string in shell script using a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306007/replace-a-string-in-shell-script-using-a-variable)

However, I get an error:

> sed: 1: "s/sceneFilePath:.*/scen ...": bad flag in substitute command:
>   'v'

Comment: Use different delimiters in sed which don't appear in you filepaths/names. `s#somthing#$var#`. You probably don't need to `g` flag either. You also don't need to run it in a subshell using `\`\``. You can run the command as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var='.\/video\/example.mp4'
sed -i '' "s/sceneFilePath:.*/sceneFilePath: \"$var\",/g" test
```

Else:

```
var='./video/example.mp4'
sed -i '' "s#sceneFilePath:.*#sceneFilePath: \"$var\",#g" test
```