# How do I get sed to use a user input variable?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

It doesn't seem like sed is aware of the $IP variable.
How can I get the following to work?

```
read -p "Please enter the line number with the IP you wish to block from accessing the Internet? " IP

echo $IP

IP_LINE_NUMBER=`nmap -n -sn 192.168.3.0/24 -oG - | awk '/Up$/{print $2}' | sed  '$IPq;d'`

echo $IP_LINE_NUMBER
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace a string in shell script using a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306007/replace-a-string-in-shell-script-using-a-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use double quotes and put `{}` around `IP`:

```
ip_line_number=$(nmap -n -sn 192.168.3.0/24 -oG - | awk '/Up$/{print $2}' | sed  "${IP}q;d")
```

- Note: you need command substitution `$(...)` to get the output into your variable

See also:

- [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)
- [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Comment: Corrected - needed a `{}` around the variable.  Please try.

Comment: I'm sorry, bud but it yields this error:  sed: -e expression #1, char 3: `}' doesn't want any addresses

Comment: I apologize. You were right.  THANKS!  It works.  Have a great day!