# Variables not working in sed command

Tags: shell, sed

How to use a variable instead of `3` in the command below?

```
sed -i '3s/$/ newvalue/' filename
```

I tried

```
var=1
sed -i '$vars/$/ newvalue/' filename
sed -i "$vars/$/ newvalue/" filename
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace a string in shell script using a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306007/replace-a-string-in-shell-script-using-a-variable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to use [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) to allow shell parameters/variables to expand. Then, you need to use [braces to isolate the variable name](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) if text that follows the variable could be interpreted as part of variable name (`before${var}after`). Finally, to use literal `$` under double quotes, you should escape it a blackslash. All together:

```
var=3
sed -i "${var}s/\$/ newvalue/" filename
```

One alternative is to use alternating double and single quotes (under which no character is treated specially, including `$` for parameter expansion):

```
sed -i "$var"'s/$/ newvalue/' filename
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems that `sed "${var}s/$/ newvalue/" filename` works fine too without the escape before `$`

Comment: It works in this case because "/" that follows is not a valid variable name. But in general, you should escape "$" under double quotes. Have in mind valid variable names are not just alphanumeric strings, but also special shell variables, like ?, !, #, etc.

Comment: That's definitely a more safer syntax, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @ randomir : thanks its working . sed -i "${var}s/\$/ newvalue/"

Comment: One more query., please help !! How to remove blank space from end of the file?

Comment: @JegaB, what kind of blank space, blank lines? You can try with `sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' file`. This will remove *all* lines with only whitespace characters (but not only at the end of file).

Comment: @ randomir :  Thank you soo much.. your solution solved my problem.