# For loop with sed textfile (Bash) - code not doing what wanted

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, sed

I've got the following paragraph (saved on a file text.txt):

```
Good morning, my name is Maria.
I study in the university. 
I like to travel.
```

And I would like to end up with three paragraphs exactly like that one but with different female names. Desired output:

```
Good morning, my name is Maria.
I study in the university. 
I like to travel.

Good morning, my name is Lola.
I study in the university. 
I like to travel.

Good morning, my name is Veronica.
I study in the university. 
I like to travel.
```

So I made a txt file with the names, names.txt:

```
Maria
Lola
Veronica
```

And I wanted to come up with a for loop that iterates the paragraph but replaces the names with sed. So I did:

```
for i in names.txt; do sed 's/Maria/"$i"/g' text.txt; done
```

But what I get is this:

```
Good morning, my name is "$i".
I study in the university. 
I like to travel.
```

Someone knows what could be wrong in my code? Thank you!

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306007/replace-a-string-in-shell-script-using-a-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
for i in $(< names.txt); do
    sed "s/Maria\./$i\n/g" text.txt
    echo # newline
done
```

Quoting issue and your forgot to read the file. That's what I do with

```
$(< names.txt)
```

"Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: Thank you ! and thanks for the explanation and links :)