# Use sed to replace regex with a variable

Tags: bash, variables, sed

I'm trying to create a bash script where I can replace a date in a filename with the current date, however, I'm not being able to do so.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_file="FILENAME_20170410235908_GTT_DEV_20170410235400_20170410235408_XX_YY.nc"

my_date=`date "+%Y%m%d"`

echo "$my_file" | sed  's/\([0-9]\{12\}\)/"${my_date}"/g'
```

I'm currently getting this:

```
FILENAME_"${my_date}"08_GTT_DEV_"${my_date}"00_"${my_date}"08_XX_YY.nc
```

Howerver, this is what I'd like to have:

```
FILENAME_2019070135908_GTT_DEV_20190701235400_20190701235408_XX_YY.nc
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed substitution with bash variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace a string in shell script using a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306007/replace-a-string-in-shell-script-using-a-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
sed "s/\([0-9]\+\)/${my_date}/g"
```

single quote will not replace variable data.
`my_date` will have only date. If you want the timestamp also, add it from the date command.