# How to used "Unix built in Command in sed"

Tags: linux, sed

I have file like below

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
10.120.6.19 slatbnrduva00.ad.admin slatbnrduva00
#172.25.17.75 infrbaddc01.ad.lab
```

Where "slatbnrduva00" is my hostname. Now i am trying to delete that line using sed as below

```
sed -i '/`hostname`/d' myhost
```

but it is not deleting that line. Please let me know how to use built in linux command in sed

Comment: backtick is not special within single quotes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680504/sed-substitution-with-bash-variables and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace a string in shell script using a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306007/replace-a-string-in-shell-script-using-a-variable)

Comment: `sed -i '/slatbnrduva00/d' file`

Comment: sed -i "/`hostname`/d" myhost ---> Finally this code worked

Answer (score 2):

Unix built in commands need to be `expanded`.

You can do :

> $(hostname)

or

> `hostname`

But back-tics is old and deprecated.

To expand commands in sed, you need to use double quote `"`.  With singel quote `'` no expand.

So this should be the best why to do it:

```
sed -i "/$(hostname)/d" file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep`:

```
grep -vFw "$(hostname -f)" file
```

`-v` reverse the match, which would effectively remove lines containing the hostname. `-F` will treat the search pattern as a fixed string rather than a  regular expression. Meaning the `.` in the hostname means a literal `.`, not *any character*. `-w` matches at word boundaries meaning `bar.baz.com` would not match `foobar.baz.com`