# Replace String between two patterns

Tags: shell

Original String: `allow from 1.1.1.1 9.9.9.9 2.2.2.2`

I wanted to replace `9.9.9.9` with `5.5.5.5` e.g. `allow from 1.1.1.1 5.5.5.5 2.2.2.2`

The Goal is to Replace any string between `allow from 1.1.1.1` and `2.2.2.2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace a string in shell script using a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306007/replace-a-string-in-shell-script-using-a-variable)

Comment: Nope. I need to replace an "unknown string" between two patters, thats possible if the string to be replace is known but in my case it's not known; so I think it will be possible to get those unknown string to be replace using known patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that the rest of the line is always `allow from 1.1.1.1` before the part you want to modify and `2.2.2.2` after the part you want to modify. Try:

```sh
string1="allow from 1.1.1.1 9.9.9.9 2.2.2.2"
new=5.5.5.5
string2=$(echo "$string1" | sed "/^\(allow from 1\.1\.1\.1\) .* \(2\.2\.2\.2\)$/s//\1 $new \2/")
```

If you are not sure of having always `1.1.1.1` or `2.2.2.2`, you will have to modify the regex accordingly, which is quite trivial, as in:

```
string2=$(echo "$string1" | sed "/^\(allow from [^ ]*\) .* \([^ ]*\)$/s//\1 $new \2/")
```

Comment: I edited the sed regex to sed `"/\(allow from 1\.1\.1\.1\) .* \(2\.2\.2\.2\)/s//\1 $new \2/"` for cases which the original string has content in the start and at the end string. But it works! Thanks! Accepting the answer..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
new="5.5.5.5" perl -pe 's/(allow from 1.1.1.1 ).*?( 2.2.2.2)/$1$ENV{new}$2/' $YOUR_FILE
```

Given a file containing

```
allow from 1.1.1.1 9.9.9.9 2.2.2.2
allow from 1.1.1.1 x 2.2.2.2
allow from 1.1.1.1 3.3.3 2.2.2.2
```

It will output this:

```
allow from 1.1.1.1 5.5.5.5 2.2.2.2
allow from 1.1.1.1 5.5.5.5 2.2.2.2
allow from 1.1.1.1 5.5.5.5 2.2.2.2
```

It replaced anything between "allow from 1.1.1.1 " and " 2.2.2.2" with the content of the variable `$new` defined in front of the perl command.

If you want to make sure you only replace groups of 4 digits separated by dots, you can replace `.*?` in the regex with something like `\d\.\d\.\d\.\d`. If these are IPv4 addresses you could also use `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}` or the less sctrict `[\d\.]{7,15}` (7 to 15 characters, all dots or digits).

If you want to do it "in-place" instead of printing the result to STDOUT, you can add `-i.bak` as the first option. That will first backup "$YOUR_FILE" to "$YOUR_FILE.bak"

Answer (score 0):

I'd use awk, and pass the IP addresses in as parameters:

```sh
awk -v start="1.1.1.1" -v end="2.2.2.2" -v repl="5.5.5.5" '
    /allow from/ && $3 == start && $5 == end {$4 = repl}
    {print}
' file
```

If you need to save that file in-place, there are several options:

```
awk ... file > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file
awk ... file | sponge file                   # requires the `moreutils` package
awk -i inplace -v ... file                   # requires GNU awk
```