# Swap variable within a command

Tags: shell, unix

I have a command that works fine and looks like this:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --format json --batch=true 'select * from `ga4-extract.analytics_123456789.events_20220722` limit 1;' > data.json
```

I would like to make this part of the command `20220722` a variable.

```
export rundate="20220722"
```

Tried just:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --format json --batch=true 'select * from `ga4-extract.analytics_123456789.events_$rundate` limit 1;' > data.json
```

This ran the command without variable substitution.

I read [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306007/replace-a-string-in-shell-script-using-a-variable) but it looks like it's more about manipulating a string rather than an entire command. Nevertheless, from that post I tried swapping single for double quotes:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --format json --batch=true "select * from `ga4-extract.analytics_123456789.events_$rundate` limit 1;" > data.json
bash: ga4-extract.analytics_302644320.events_20220722: command not found
```

Is it possible to swap out a variable within a command, as opposed to within a string? What's the 'right' way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: If input is trusted, you can replace `$rundate` in the query by `'"$rundate"'`. If input is untrusted, don't subsitute unless you have carefully sanitised against injection attacks.

Comment: single-quoted strings are not expanded by the shell. double-quoted strings are. Inside double-quoted strings, backticks are an old way of writing `$(...)` which executes the command given inside.

Comment: in some queries, you can do substitution like: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#bq

Comment: Thanks! That 3rd comment could help me here and now, but I'd like to know how to do this in unix more generally, for example I tried your first suggestion with: `bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --format json --batch=true 'select * from `ga4-extract.analytics_123456.events_'"$rundate'"` limit 1;' > data.json` and the console seems stuck, it's been like this for ten mins after submitting the query which usually runs in single digit seconds

Comment: not `'"$rundate'"`, `'"$rundate"'`. you need to match up start/end of single/double quoting. with the command you show in your comment, your console is waiting for the end of a backtick command